# How to use NIntegrate in a function using parameters from a list

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value

I would like to use `NIntegrate` in a function with some parameters from a list. I simplified my problem for this forum. The list of parameters is as follows:

```
aH = {aH1, aH2};
pars = {aH1 -> 2., aH2 -> 3.};
```

Normal integration works fine. The next function gives numerical output for numerical values of t and T.

```
f[t_, T_, k_Integer]:=Exp[-Integrate[aH[[k]],{u,t,T}]]
```

Now I would like to define the function using `NIntegrate`

```
f[t_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, k_Integer, aH1_?NumericQ] := Exp[-NIntegrate[aH[[k]], {u, t, T}]]
```

Unfortunately, this does not give numerical output when trying to evaluate by:

```
f[0., 1., 1, 2.]
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Your help is much appreciated.

Best regards,

Frits

Comment: In your last definition there is aH1 (which must be a NumericQ not a list) on the LHS and aH  (which is by implication a list) on the RHS?  What is u in this context?

Comment: Well, actually I meant to write it this way. The reason being that in my actual problem there are summations over multiple indices of k.

Comment: Your aH1 argument on LHS is not used on the RHS.  The RHS references the global symbol aH.

Comment: When I enter `Evaluate` at two places, I do get a correct answer: `f[t_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, k_Integer, aH1_?NumericQ] := 
 Exp[-NIntegrate[aH[[k]] // Evaluate, {u, t, T}]] // Evaluate`

Comment: I too am puzzled by the example, perhaps something got lost in translation to 'simplified'. e.g., where does `pars` come into play? OP, is aH supposed to be some index into a set of functions on `u`? If so, just make a list assigned to `aH` and index into it as required.

Comment: In the end I need to estimate the values in pars in a `FindFit` procedure. That is the reason why I cannot set them upfront.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a function whith NIntegrate, and paramters as arguments of the function

```
f[t_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, aH1_?NumericQ] := Exp[-NIntegrate[aH1, {u, t, T}]]

f[0., 1., 2.] = 0.135335
```