# How to involve a variable in numerical integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Now I have two functions f[x] and g[x] which both contains another variable a, or we can note as f[a,x] and g[a,x]. Now I need to solve the equation 
`Solve[Integrate[f[a,x],{x,0,2Pi}]==Integrate[g[a,x],{x,0,2Pi}],a]`
to solve the value of a, however, f and g are both hard to do an analytical integral. So now I have to use NIntegrate instead, but the NIntegrate function seems cannot contain a variable a in it.

What can I do to solve the a?

Update:
 I can show the example of f[x] and g[x] as follow.

```
f[abratio_] := 
  Integrate[(\[Zeta]1[\[Theta]] \[Zeta]2[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]]^4)/(
   DD[\[Theta]] (abratio^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2)^(3/
       2)), {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}];
g[abratio_] := 
  Integrate[(\[Zeta]1[\[Theta]] \[Zeta]2[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]]^2 \
Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(
   DD[\[Theta]] (abratio^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2)^(3/
       2)), {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}];
```

or

$$f(a)=\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{\zeta_1(\theta)\zeta_2(\theta)\cos^4(\theta)}{DD(\theta)[a^2 \cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)]^{3/2}}d\theta $$
$$g(a)=\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{\zeta_1(\theta)\zeta_2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta) \sin^2(\theta)}{DD(\theta)[a^2 \cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)]^{3/2}}d\theta $$

where $\zeta$ and DD are other functions about $\theta$.

Comment: What reason do you have to believe there is an unique solution for `a`?  (For example, suppose `f=a+Sin` and `g=a+Cos`, etc.)

Comment: @Alan Yes it's a equation in a paper that I was reading. It is right and the author gave out numerical solution to the problem.

Comment: See [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42085/numerical-integration-with-variable-parameters) [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40835/how-to-use-nintegrate-in-a-function-using-parameters-from-a-list) [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99085/numerical-integration-with-parameter-and-plot) etc.

Comment: I should add that a simple search of MSE using "numerical integration parameter" (without quotes) gives multiple hits for how to do this sort of thing e.g. using `_?NumericQ` restrictions on variables.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes it works,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the functions f[a] and g[a] to be only defined for numerical input, like:

```
f[abratio_?NumericQ] := 
  Integrate[(\[Zeta]1[\[Theta]] \[Zeta]2[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]]^4)/(
   DD[\[Theta]] (abratio^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2)^(3/
       2)), {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}];
g[abratio_?NumericQ] := 
  Integrate[(\[Zeta]1[\[Theta]] \[Zeta]2[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Theta]]^2 \
Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(
   DD[\[Theta]] (abratio^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2)^(3/
       2)), {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}];
```

Then you can numerical solve for a using FindRoot:

```
FindRoot[f[a]==g[a], {a,a0}]
```

where a0 is an initial numerical guess for a.